# Using a loaded tensorflow model outside of session

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I want to load a TensorFlow model (checkpoint) and use in in a while loop.

Loading the model takes some time, so I want to do that before the while loop. 
If I use:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print("loading checkpoint ...")
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(str(modelpath / 'mfn.ckpt.meta'))
        saver.restore(sess, str(modelpath / 'mfn.ckpt'))

while: 
...
```

the problem is that the session is closed after the end of while.
I saw now [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850866/error-while-trying-to-save-tensorflow-checkpoint-with-savedmodelbuilder-for-tens) about a similar problem.

The answer seemed to be using TensorFlow Serving. Unfortunately, therefore the model has to be in the format of SavedModel class. I do not have a SavedModel but only the checkpoints.

I tried saving the loaded checkpoint with the `tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder()`
but ran into some issues. I made a post about those issues separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850866/error-while-trying-to-save-tensorflow-checkpoint-with-savedmodelbuilder-for-tens).

**Is there another way of running a loaded model (as in the code above) outside of a session?**

Answer (score 0):

From your illustration code, I guess you're using TensorFlow version 1.x (with tf.Graph, tf.Session ...). Is this right?

So, about your question: "Is there another way of running a loaded model (as in the code above) outside of a session?",

I have a suggestion: have you ever tried to convert your code to TensorFlow version 2.x?

If you can do this, after that:

- You can easily save-load your TF model using tf.saved_model.save() and tf.saved_model.load() methods,
- Then, use the loaded model easily in a while loop.